Excel Function: Using a specific criteria to form an array to corresponding values
I have a problem whereby I am unable to form an array based on a certain criteria and have been racking my brains for hours & would appreciate any assistance on this.
I have a massive data dump containing of an ID tag (non-unique) to the client's name in which if they are from the same family they will be tagged to the same ID. I am trying to create an array as shown in Sheet 2 based on the criteria in Column A.
Sheet1: Containing the Raw Data file that I have.



ID
Names




1
John


2
Alan


3
Ray


2
David


2
Sean


2
Darren


1
Jerry


1
Charles


3
Kelvin



Sheet2: How I want the data to populate based on criteria in column.



ID
Name1
Name2
Name3
Name4




1
John
Jerry
Charles



2
Alan
David
Sean
Darren


3
Ray
Kelvin





Sheet1: Containing the Raw Data file that I have
Sheet2: How I want the data to populate based on criteria in column A
Appreciate any inputs on this please!
I've tried to use a number of formulas consisting of SMALL/ROW and using Ctrl+Shift+Enter but it always turns out a blank or error.

Glad our answers helped. In the future, you should submit comments here as opposed to  writing an answer as a comment - stack overflow has a different format than forum sites. Also, based on your username I recommend you checking out https://chandoo.org/ which is where I learned to love what excel could do almost 15 years ago. good luck!

This may be even more intimidating, lol.
If you have acces to PIVOTBY (Office 365)
=PIVOTBY(A2:A10,"Name "&MAP(A2:A10,LAMBDA(a,SUM(N(A2:a=a)))),B2:B10,CONCAT,,0,,0)

This uses column A as a vertical identifier and the MAP formula creates a cumulative counter for the count of each single ID MAP(A2:A10,LAMBDA(a,SUM(N(A2:a=a)))) for horizontal usage. I simply added "Name " in front of the counter values.
If we use the names as values and perform function CONCAT on the values it displays the values where they meet the (since they're always single values, else we would've used ARRAYTOTEXT).

@tryingtolearnexcel This should be accepted answer.

I was using SINGLE() all these while. but seems CONCAT() works the same way here

Single works as well. Didn't know I had access to that yet. Thanks

You may try the following formula-
=IFERROR(HSTACK(UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A10),
DROP(REDUCE("",UNIQUE(Sheet1!A2:A10),
LAMBDA(a,x,VSTACK(a,TOROW(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:B10,Sheet1!A2:A10=x,""),1)))),1)),"")



Assuming you have Excel 2021 or 365, you can FILTER the range by a criteria, in this case, the family ID, and then take a UNIQUE of the resulting names. Finally, use the `TRANSPOSE function to make the vertical list into a horizontal one.
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B10,(A2:A10=D2))))

